# Can't access index.gsp in grails

Tags: grails, gsp, grails-controller

I am new to grails and I am trying to access index page. After deleting the default homepage for grails, I getting the following error
    404 App1/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/index.jsp

```
description The requested resource is not available.
```

I checked UrlMapping and view is set to index

```
    "/"(view:"/index")
    "500"(view:'/error')
```

My controller class

```
package  App1grailsapp

class TeamController {

 def index() { }

    def teams()
    {
        [teams:Team.list()]
    }


}
```

And I have two gsp pages,

index

```
<!--
  To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
  To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
  and open the template in the editor.
-->

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Sample title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h2><g:message code="welcome"/></h2>

        <ul>
            <li><g:link action="teams">Display all teams</g:link></li>

        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

and teams

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main">
        <title>Teams</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Teams:</h2>

        <table>
            <tr>
            <thead>
                <th>Name</th>

            </thead>
            </tr>
            <g:each var="team" in="${teams}">
                <tr>
                    <td>${team.name}</td>

                </tr>
            </g:each>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't understand why index.gsp page is not being shown?

Comment: Where are your GSP pages located in your project?

Comment: under views and layouts

Comment: based on what you have posted you should have index.gsp under grails-app/views/team/index.gsp this is the view that is going to be rendered when you visit the teams URI. However, I don't think that's what you intend. If you want to display teams.gsp you need to render(view: 'teams', model: [teams: Teams.list()]) and have teams.gsp under grails-app/views/team/teams.gsp. The default index.gsp should be under grails-app/views/index.gsp

Comment: yes that's right it's under view/team/index.gsp but it isn't displaying

Comment: Take a look at my answer. If you are still confused we can start a chat/conversation and I can walk you through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View resolution for Grails is based on convention. Each controller has a directory under grails-app/views for their associated views. Unless you specify otherwise (via render) the view displayed will match the controller action name.

In your case you need to move your `index.gsp` to `grails-app/views/` and rename your `teams.gsp` to `index.gsp` under `grails-app/views/team`.

Hope this helps. You may want to take a look at the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/guide/theWebLayer.html#controllers) for further information and insight.

Also, you will need to specify what controller is used by the link to show all teams.

```
<li><g:link controller="team" action="index">Display all teams</g:link></li>
```